# RRULE google-rfc-2445 with hour and seconds

Tags: java, jodatime, rfc2445, rrule, rfc5545

I'm working with the implementation google-rfc-2445 (https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) to generate the date which should be repeated following an event, not as a rule indicate (RRULE) that the repetition is done taking also note the time, ie the date is calculated next time I throw too.

```
example:
Start Date: 17/04/2013 8:30 a.m.
Rule: "RRULE: FREQ = DAILY; UNTIL = 20130430T083000Z, INTERVAL = 1"
Expected Result, Next Repetition: 4/18/2013 8:30 a.m.
Result Obtained, Next Repetition: 4/18/2013 00 00 00
```

This is the code I'm using

```
 LocalDate start = new LocalDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            String ical = "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;"
                    + "UNTIL=20130430T083000Z;"
                    + "INTERVAL=1;";

            //Next Notification
            Date f = null;

            for (LocalDate date
                    : LocalDateIteratorFactory.createLocalDateIterable(ical, start, false)) {
                 f  = date.toDateTimeAtCurrentTime().toLocalDate().toDate();
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Next = " + f);
```

The printing result is
**Next = Wed Apr 17 00:00:00 COT 2013**

It is the existence of "BYHOUR = 8; BYMINUTE = 05; BYSECOND = 10" but not how to use it, if I can lend a hand, thank you.

Comment: Your RRULE seems to be malformed.  It contains commas where there should be a semicolon and extraneous spaces.  What is the exact rule you're using?

Comment: RRULE: FREQ = DAILY; UNTIL = 20130430T083000Z, INTERVAL = 1

Comment: I see `String ical` in your code sample which includes the correct punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LocalDateIteratorFactory` produces dates without a corresponding time, but it sounds like you want DateTimes.  Use [`DateTimeIteratorFactory`](http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/snapshot/docs/com/google/ical/compat/jodatime/DateTimeIteratorFactory.html) instead.

Also,

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

is probably not equivalent to

```
Start Date: 17/04/2013 8:30 a.m.
```

You probably want to use [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 4, 17, 8, 30, 0);
```

Finally, there's no reason to use the Joda time compatibility layer if what you want at the end is

```
Date f = null;
```

Just use the [`java.util` compatibility layer](http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/snapshot/docs/com/google/ical/compat/javautil/DateIteratorFactory.html) instead.

I would suggest sticking to Joda time though, since `java.util` dates are a mess.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to indicate the start time in the RRULE? , For no DateTime start, but from the current date.

Comment: @GustavoSalgado, No.  RFC-2445 requires both to specify the behavior of an RRULE, and doesn't specify a syntax for combining them.

Comment: For serves then "BYHOUR = 8; BYMINUTE = 05; BYSECOND = 10" ?